# Heapsort With Full-Scale Genericity

Tags: c++, algorithm, template, iterator, heap-sort

I've written a [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) implementation. It's generic: generic comparators and sequences with elements of a generic type.

The implementation (follows closely chapter 6 from *Introduction to Algorithms 3<sup>rd</sup> Edition* and) consists of

1. `heapify`: establishes the heap property for an element:

   ```
   template<typename BiDirIterator, typename Cmp>
   void heapify(BiDirIterator begin, BiDirIterator end,
   typename std::iterator_traits<BiDirIterator>::difference_type i, Cmp cmp)
   {
       const auto dist = std::distance(begin, end);

       while (true) {
           auto left = 2 * i + 1;
           auto right = left + 1;
           typename std::iterator_traits<BiDirIterator>::value_type largest;

           if (left < dist && cmp(begin[left], begin[i]))
               largest = left;
           else
               largest = i;
           if (right < dist && cmp(begin[right], begin[largest]))
               largest = right;

           if (largest == i)
               break;

           std::swap(begin[i], begin[largest]);
           i = largest;
       }
   }
   ```
2. `buildHeap`: creates a heap from a permutation:

   ```
   template<typename BiDirIterator, typename Cmp>
   void buildHeap(BiDirIterator begin, BiDirIterator end, Cmp cmp)
   {
       for (auto i = std::distance(begin, end) / 2 - 1; i >= 1; --i)
           heapify(begin, end, i, cmp);
       heapify(begin, end, 0, cmp);
   }
   ```
3. `sort`: applies Heapsort to retrieve an ordered sequence from the permutation:

   ```
   template<typename BiDirIterator, typename Cmp>
   void sort(BiDirIterator begin, BiDirIterator end, Cmp cmp)
   {
       buildHeap(begin, end, cmp);
       for (auto i = std::distance(begin, end) - 1; i > 0; --i) {
           std::swap(*begin, begin[i]);
           heapify(begin, std::next(begin, i - 1), 0, cmp);
       }
   }
   ```

Necessary includes are:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
```

In action:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> perm { 5, 6, 9, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 87, 4 };

    heap::sort(perm.begin(), perm.end(), heap::max<int>{});
}
```

where the `heap` utilities are put into a separate `heap` namespace and `heap::max` is simply

```
template<typename T> using max = std::greater<T>;
```

Some questions:

1. Is it OK to use `Cmp` as a template parameter? That makes it more generic, but the error messages are way more complicated and point to stuff deep down in the implementation. (Granted, you can't say *my* implementation is anywhere close to "deep," but this is more of a general question.) Passing a `Cmp`, where `Cmp` is some alias for a type, would also be possible but not as generic. `std::sort` also uses the template parameter, though, so I do so as well.
2. Is my use of iterators alright? I tried to keep the interface clean with iterators for interaction with standard containers, but the implementation also uses numerical indices when it's more convenient.
3. `heapify` is ugly: there's an infinite loop with a `break` condition and it basically finds the largest element out of three while checking that they are within range (i.e., `< dist`). I have a feeling this can be beautified both syntactically and semantically. Some hint on that would be appreciated.
4. The implementation is supposed to work with bidirectional iterators. `std::list` doesn't work because subscripting is not supported, it's not efficient for `std::list`, etc. Should I replace subscripting with `std::next` to make it work on `std::list` at the cost of performance guarantees? `std::list` would work, but it might be frickin' slow asymptotically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`left = 2 * i + 1;` for a non-random access iterator this is an operation that is linear with regards to `i` so it's slow for std::list as well.

Heapify can be adust to not need to `std::advance` an arbitrary amount by going over the list multiple times:

```
template<typename BiDirIterator, typename Cmp>
void heapify(BiDirIterator begin, BiDirIterator end, Cmp cmp)
{
    bool changed = false;
    do{
        auto parent = begin;
        auto left = begin == end? end : begin+1;
        auto right = left == end? end : left+1;
        while (left != end) {
            auto largest = left
            if (right != end && cmp(*left, *right))
                largest = right;

            if (cmp(*parent, *largest)){
                std::swap(*parent, *largest);
                changed = true;
            }

            parent = ++parent;
            left = right == end? end : right+1;
            right = left == end? end : left+1;
        }
    }while(changed);
}
```

This will loop over the data at most O(log n) times and puts the elements in heap order.

However for pulling out the data there is no way to only look at the affected elements in O(log n) time. Which means that you can't sort a linked list with heapsort and still be in O(n log n) time complexity.

Instead to sort a linked list in O(n log n) time you would use merge sort. This requires that you are able to be able to split the list up into separate linked lists in that you can merge. std::list has this functionality with it's `splice` member function. (It also has a `sort` member function that will do that built-in)